# How to know if a user has visited all the pages of a pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, mozilla, pdf.js

How while using MOzilla pdf.js I may know if some user has visited all the pages of the pdf, so that we can set some event occuring after he visited all the pages.

I needed a button to be active once user completes all his pages, otherwise not.